# Whenever a linear operator behave like polynomial in other linear operator.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

> Let $V$ be a space of polynomials of degree $\leq 3$. Let $T$ and $D$ be  linear operators on $V$ such that $T(f(t))=f(t+1)$ and $D(f(t))=f'(t)$, then $T$ is a polynomial in $D$.

This statement is true or not?

I think I don't understand it so well.
Why $T$ is a polynomial in $D$.
Even when range of $D$ contains polynomial of degree 2 at most.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

Standard basis of given vector space: $\{1,x,x^2,x^3\}$

$T(1)=1$

$T(x)=x+1$

$T(X^2)=x^2+2x+1$

$T(x^3)=x^3+3x^2+3x+1$

So matrix form of T in standard basis is 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 &1 \\ 
0 & 1 & 2 & 3\\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 3\\ 
 0& 0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}

Similarly,

$D(1)=0$

$D(x)=1$

$D(X^2)=2x$

$D(x^3)=3x^2$

So matrix form of T in standard basis is 
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 &0\\ 
0 & 0 & 2 & 0\\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 3\\ 
 0& 0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}

**Verify:** **$$T=1/6D^3+1/6D^2+I$$**